# How to remove/add class on main parent

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hi please see code below:

My goal is if I click the 1st button it will add class on `main` parent and if I click it again it will remove class. But if I click the other button the class on 1st `main` parent will remove and it will add to 2nd `main` parent. Can anyone help me how to accomplish that?

```js
$(".main-btn").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".main").addClass("addClass");
});
```

```css
.main {
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  
}

.main.addClass {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
        <div class="main-btn">Button</div>
  <div class="main-wrapper">
  </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
  </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="main-btn">Button</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="main-btn">Button</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it via below functions:

1. [**siblings()**](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to get siblings elements and remove the `addClass`
2. [**toggle()**](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to switch the class of current clicked element

```js
$(".main-btn").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".main").siblings().removeClass("addClass");
  $(this).closest(".main").toggleClass("addClass");
});
```

```css
.main {
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  
}

.addClass {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
        <div class="main-btn">Button</div>
  <div class="main-wrapper">
  </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
  </div>
    <div class="main-wrapper">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="main-btn">Button</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="main-btn">Button</div>
</div>
```